# Turning ascii code to a string

Tags: c, string, ascii, printf

I'm having a problem to turn ascii code in a vector to a string... example...

```
main(){
    //Having 'abcdefhgijkl', the position 0 is 'l'.
    int x[3] ={0};
    x[2] = ('a'<<24) + ('b'<<16) + ('c'<<8) + 'd';
    x[1] = ('e'<<24) + ('f'<<16) + ('g'<<8) + 'h';
    x[0] = ('i'<<24) + ('j'<<16) + ('k'<<8) + 'l';

    int i = 0;
    char buf[12];

    while(i < sizeof(x)){
        sprintf(buf,"%d",x[i]);
        printf("%s \n", buf);
        i++;
    }
}
```

My intention  is to print 'abcdefghijkl' but the output is numbers... I have done many search but nothing seems to work, i tried fucntion itoa, snprintf and now sprintf and nothing seems to work.

Comment: why not just `printf("abcdefghijkl");`?

Comment: because im learning and i want to know how to turn those integers into strings...

Comment: Firstly sizeof returns the length in bytes of an array, not the number of elements, secondly indexing into an array accesses the the nth element not the nth byte. Thirdly you need to cast your value in x to char and use a "%c" format. Finally you'll need to take [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) into account if you want to write this in a portable way.

Comment: What language? C? Java? C++? GolfScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some improvements to your program:

- To do what you are trying to do with the sprintf call you must use
  `%s` to read it as a string, and not `%d` which will just give you
  numbers. Since these "strings" are not real nul-terminated strings,
  you must limit the length of the string to 4 bytes with `%.4s`.
- The array x has three elements, but sizeof(x) returns the size in
  bytes which is 12 (usually). So in order to iterate three times you
  need to calculate total size divided by the size of one element. That
  will give you number of elements (a common way to do this in a
  general way it to `#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))`.
- The buf variable is too small, you need to increase by one to have
  room for the 12 characters + one byte for the nul termination
  character `\0`.
- If you want "abcdefghijkl" as output you need either to reverse the order of
  x initialization or you need to reverse the loop to start with the highest number
  and run down to zero. And even then you run into [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues.
- The loop can preferably be converted to a for loop.
- The main function ought to have a proper signature.

Testing with

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int x[3] ={0};
    x[0] = ('a'<<24) + ('b'<<16) + ('c'<<8) + 'd';
    x[1] = ('e'<<24) + ('f'<<16) + ('g'<<8) + 'h';
    x[2] = ('i'<<24) + ('j'<<16) + ('k'<<8) + 'l';

    int i;
    char buf[12 + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(x)/sizeof(int); i++){
        sprintf(buf,"%.4s", (char *)&x[i]);
        printf("%s \n", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it gives the following output:

```
dcba
hgfe
lkji
```

Answer (score 0):

The below modified program will output "abcdefghijkl"

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

   //Having 'abcdefhgijkl', the position 0 is 'l'.
   int x[3] ={0};
   int n = 0;
   x[2] = ('a'<<24) + ('b'<<16) + ('c'<<8) + 'd';
   x[1] = ('e'<<24) + ('f'<<16) + ('g'<<8) + 'h';
   x[0] = ('i'<<24) + ('j'<<16) + ('k'<<8) + 'l';

   int i = 0;
   char buf[12+1] = {'\0'};
   char *ptr = (char*)x + sizeof(x)-1;


   while(i < sizeof(x)){
      sprintf(((char*)buf+i),"%c",*ptr);
      i++;
      ptr--; 
   } 

   printf("The string is = %s\n",buf);
}
```